# jQuery API-compatible micro framework (other than Zepto)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would swear on my cat's grave that I just read about such a thing in the last couple weeks, but I can't for the life of me find it now. I am looking for a minimal framework covering basic DOM selecting (e.g., including Sizzle, so it works with IE6 -- so Zepto doesn't qualify), manipulation & event binding, but omitting just about everything else.

I need to add some very simple stuff to a VERY old web site and I want to use jQuery compatible syntax in case one day it needs more, but don't want to add 90K to the page size for this. I was hoping to spend approximately 30 minutes on this project, so I don't really want to cobble this together myself. Assuming I'm not imagining things, anyone know what I might be thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be [Midori](http://www.midorijs.com/) perhaps?

Edit: Now that I remember there's also [DOMAssistant](http://www.domassistant.com/), which is supposed to support Sizzle-style selectors and IE 5.5+.

Comment: Well it looks like yours may be the only answer I get! Neither of these look like they're trying to be jQuery API compatible, though   DOMAssistant as you note does seem close enough as far as selectors go. But it also seems like it might be dead. Which is too bad - because it actually looks exactly like the kind of thing I'm looking for. But reading about it in its discussion forums did lead me to what I might have been thinking of: **ender.js** http://ender.no.de/ so I'm giving it to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Since November 2016 there's also [ZebraJS](https://github.com/stefangabos/zebrajs) and I am its author.

Comment: Seems we came up with more or less the same idea at more at less the same time...

Comment: Indeed! :) Thanks for adding it to your chart!

Answer (score 1):

Since May 2016, there is also [picoQuery](http://picoquery.com) and I am its author...