# Jquery to javascript for small device, light code needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay so I'm new to javascript but I can handle jquery quite well... but jquery on a small mobile web experience is realy heavy... some time it's even too mutch.

so I have this code that simply pop's up my menu bar and i wondered if there was any light way of geting this?

```
$(function() {
    $('div.menu').hide();
    $("img#menu").click(function () {
          $("div#menu").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: "any light way of geting this?" what's a light way and getting what?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Do you want animation, hide/show and event handlers without jQuery?  If so, I'd suggest CSS3 animations, addEventListener and setting the style value directly.  Or do you just want to hide/show it on mobile without jQuery?

Comment: I want to hide and show with an animation that make the div apear from right to left on click with out jquery because it is realy too heavy for some phone like the one i have to test with

Comment: According to your code you have both an image and a div with the same ID...

Comment: @Kolink - looks like a class to me? Did you atleast try to do this without jQuery UI, which I'm assuming you're using ?

Comment: Quite right and I didn't realized yet... just changed it for menucall

Comment: no I did not tryed but even only jquery, its heavy im looking for a solution on jquery mobile atm but if you have any thing helpfull it would be nice

Comment: Have you tried zepto.js?  It's essentially drastically paired down jQuery.  It sits between jQuery and plain javascript. http://zeptojs.com/

Comment: Here's a start atleast -> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EUzbr/2/) ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8978850/1655332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I'd point out the following (see comments):

```
$(function() {
    // here you are searching by class name, that is going to eat CPU
    $('div.menu').hide();
    $("img#menu").click(function () {
        // here you are doing a JavaScript animation, eating more of the CPU
        $("div#menu").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
    });
});
```

Using CSS instead of JavaScript piggy backs on native code rather than interpreted JavaScript.

A trick too is that many mobile devices are optomised for 3D CSS transitions (because 3D is used to perform flip and slide functions used by the phone's own UI). So, using 3D transitions will get you even more vroom from the engine.

A jsFiddle of your code using CSS is here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/8dQMu/

A nice introduction to CSS transitions is here:

- http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/#how2use

Comment: it doesn't come out from the right but its a start. so I mix plain javascript and animated css! greatfully I know every thing about that as I state on my main question first sentence... =/

Comment: +1 for CSS tricks, but it only work on web-kit, do you know its equivalent for Geko or Tradient( not very important ).

Comment: @BigBoss - Here's the same for Gecko: http://jsfiddle.net/8dQMu/1/ IE9, which is currently used on Windows Phone AFAIK, doesn't support CSS transitions. We use JS transition libraries as a fallback for IE9. According to this, IE10 (Trident 6) will support CSS transitions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103283/does-internet-explorer-support-css-transitions

Comment: thanks so much, IE is always a little slow in supporting new feature, but so much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate menu using pure CSS and without any JavaScript, just write a css selector for mouse over of item that you want to show the menu through it, but this way you can't have effects like slide. to create that kind of effects you should read their code in jQuery and implement them in JS.
other things can also handled using source code of jquery, but for selector (like 'div.menu') you can use Sizzle from [Sizzlejs.com](http://Sizzlejs.com) this library is very small(4k gzipped and minified) and its selector engine can do whatever jQuery can( actually jQuery internally use Sizzle )

Comment: isn't it hard to mouse over on a smartphone?